# MustInherit class, derived class, and its class: how to call und initiate?

Tags: vb.net, initialization, abstract-class, derived-class

my programming language is VB.Net.

let'say I have an abstract class

```
Public MustInherit Class FR : Inherits UnmanagedObject

End Class
```

Thus, I have to write a derived class, also including Protected Overrides Sub DisposeObject()

```
Public Class derived_Class : Inherits FR
    Protected Overrides Sub DisposeObject()

    End Sub
End Class
```

How can I use the methods of FR? Where do I have to initiate the derived_class?
Do I need a third class, like this?

```
Public Class next_class
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

According to a documentation, this

```
Protected Sub New()

    End Sub
```

has to go somewhere.

**Description of the problem:** Due to the fact that 'FR' has the MustInherit keyword, I cannot write *New*. Therefore I wrote the derived class.

Could someone please help me get the whole package up and running ??? I appreciate your help. You can answer in C#, too. There are enough converters I can use, then.

Comment: Can you set the `Text` property of a form? Congratulations, you answered your own question. `Text` is a member of the `Control` class and `Form` inherits `Control`. You simply create a form instance and and use all members the same way, whether they are declared in that type or a base class. That a base class is abstract is irrelevant to accessing its members through a derived instance.

Comment: `Protected Sub New() End Sub` is used as the constructor of either the abstract class or the class that inherits from it. The constructor of the abstract class can also have parameters. The inheriting class constructors all call the base class default constructor, so you don't need `MyBase.New()`, unless you want to pass a value as argument, if the abstract class has a constructor with parameters. The inheriting class can also have a `Protected Sub New(o as [Type])` that matches a base class constructor. This constructor cannot be used when a new object is built, but it can be used internally.

Comment: `Public` and `Friend` (`internal`) methods of the abstract class are directly available in the classes that derive from it. Inheriting classes need to override `Protected MustOverride` methods of the abstract class as part of the inheritance and can override `Protected Overridable` methods. IIRC, `Protected MustInherit` (`protected abstract`) methods are not part of the language, while these are available in c#.

Comment: Thank you, @Jimi, this helps me to understand it better!